# How to install pr2 teleop on indigo

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to git clone the package from [here](https://github.com/PR2/pr2_apps/tree/indigo-devel). But after doing catkin_make I got the following error.

```
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "app_manager" with
  any of the following names:

    app_managerConfig.cmake
    app_manager-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "app_manager" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "app_manager_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "app_manager" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
pr2_apps/pr2_app_manager/CMakeLists.txt:3 (find_package)
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256142/how-to-install-pr2-teleop-on-indigo/) by [vacky11](https://answers.ros.org/users/29229/vacky11/) on ROS Answers with karma: 272 on 2017-03-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see #q252478 for instructions on how to build things from sources. Just `git clone`-ing is *not enough*.

---

Edit: `pr2_teleop` has also been released for Indigo (see the [wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_teleop)), so unless you have a good reason to build from sources, why not just use the provided binaries? A `sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-pr2-teleop` is always easier than building it yourself.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1